# How do I raise the logging level for the python gmail api?

Tags: python, logging, gmail-api

I set the log level in the file to be ERROR as suggested in this guide: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/logging

However, I'm still getting logs of the form:

```
02:19:11 queue.1 | 02:19:11 URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest
02:19:33 queue.1 | 02:19:33 Refreshing due to a 401
02:19:33 queue.1 | 02:19:33 Refreshing access_token
```

How do I prevent these from cluttering the service?

Comment: no idea. show us your code?

Comment: 401 error is thrown due to Invalid authorization header. The access token you're using is either expired or invalid. check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'd like to make the logging level higher though as well. Any idea how to do that?